# Magento filters url rewrite

Tags: php, magento, filter, url-routing

I've got one task about Layer Navigation block on site, powered by Magento.
We want to make a SEO friendly URL's in filters:

Now there are links like

```
mymagazine.ru/category/subcategory1?manufacturer=1926
```

As you see - manufacturer=1926 is a GET-parameter, which just filter the products.
So I need to make this link like

```
mymagazine.ru/category/subcategory1/my_manufacturer
```

Where "**my_manufacturer**" is an allias to "**?manufacturer=1926**".

There is one way to do this task: we can make allias for all the filter pages manually with the Magento admin. But the site got a great catalloge, so this would be too tedious. I thought, that this extentions could help me, but not in my practice...

[Yoast-landing-pages](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/Yoast/extension/1915/yoast-landing-pages)

[Fishpigs_attribute_splash_page](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/fishpig/extension/4889/fishpigs_attribute_splash_page)

If you have any thought about this problem, I would love to hear them.

Thank's for your attention!

Answer (score 1):

What I did on my store is tag those links in the layered navigation with rel="noindex,nofollow" and I put the same into the robots meta tag in the target pages. I didn't want every variation of the pages to be indexed as I don't want duplicate content. Each variation of the category pages from that layered navigation ends up having the same title, meta description, and often many of the same products.

Comment: I'd prefer to do your way or leave everything as is. But you're know that SEO-guys, they think almost about the machines, not about the users. And also that kind of customisition assume to make single landing pages for each filter variation (with own meta).